# Setting up Pi Zero with Raspbian Jessie Lite (headless) : can't find etc directory

Tags: raspbian, headless

I have a Mac, Raspberry Pi zero, and an SD card.

I downloaded Raspbian Jessie Lite and installed as per directions in [Installing operating system images on macOS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md).

I cannot find the `etc/` directory to modify the Wi-Fi configuration.  The card contains:

```
.fseventsd      bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb kernel.img
COPYING.linux       bootcode.bin        kernel7.img
LICENCE.broadcom    cmdline.txt     overlays
LICENSE.oracle      config.txt      start.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb  fixup.dat       start_cd.elf
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb   fixup_cd.dat        start_db.elf
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb  fixup_db.dat        start_x.elf
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb fixup_x.dat
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb issue.txt
```

The only directory is overlays.

Is there something I am missing? From online documents it seems the configuration should be in etc which does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two partitions on the card.  The first one is small, ~60 MB, and formatted with a FAT32 filesystem.  Pretty much any operating system can read this.  It contains the bootloader/bootstrap firmware, OS kernel, some configuration files, and a variety of device tree overlays.  That's what you are looking at.

The second partition is much larger, (I think ~2GB with jessie lite but it may be more) and formatted [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4); this is the root filesystem which contains the `/etc` directory.  When running, normally the first partition is mounted on `/boot` in the root fs hierarchy.

To read/write ext4 on OSX I believe you need third party tools or to use a [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) running some GNU/Linux based system.

Comment: Thank you! I found the easiest was to use the VM : http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/mounting-raspberry-pis-ext4-sd